# Cuda compute capability 3.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.7

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I have python 3.5, gpu: Quadro K1000M, CUDA 9.0 and I want toinstall tensorflow on gpu. The installation was done successfully, but when I check it, it gives me the warning and my python code works with CPU version in spite of I didn't install CPU version. The warning is:

```
     Cuda compute capability 3.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.7
```

When I check it in python as follow:

```
    sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
    sess.close()
```

It return me

```
    no known devices
```

Can anyone please help me what I do? I'm new in python, any hint may be useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Cuda compute capability 3.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.7

Your GPU is too old, the bare minimum according to the [list of GPU models on Wikipedia's CUDA page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) is a Tesla K80. If you want touse TF on the GPU you'll need to upgrade the GPU first.